# How to open and edit any xlsm files?

Tags: libreoffice

How to open and edit any xlsm files in ubuntu?
Is there Any offline or online tools ?
I have tried libre office and WPS office . Also tried google sheet and online Microsoft office .

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run the macros that are included/referenced in the .xlsm file on Linux then there is no software that I've come across or was able to find through searching that can do this. The major problem is that the underlying macro languages are completely different between MS Excel of LibreOffice.

Without an application your next best options are to either use something like CrossOver followed by Wine.

There is also a 3rd option, which I've never used, that's web based called Zamzar. Zamzar allows you to upload files and convert them to a variety of formats.

I tried the following answer in other forum but it didn't worked for me but you can gave a shot

[Ask ubuntu solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47660/commandline-tool-for-viewing-xls-files)